# Is it possible to rename type member names in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible, with PowerShell, to get a bunch of data, throw into a table, and then afterwards apply the name to the headers?

The issue is that I have an asynchronous operation that gets some data from a remote network location, and sometimes the header information will return first, which makes it really easy to set the headers on the table I'm populating, but sometimes that doesn't happen.  I want to be able to collect the data first while looking for the headers, and then set them after it's all been collected.

I'd prefer not to have to iterate over every single object in the table as there could be hundreds of lines of data coming back.  I'm also trying to make sure that it's generic enough that it could handle any number of headers and columns of data (the number of columns always match the number of headers, of course).

Isn't there a way to rename the properties of a `[pscustomeobject]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid doing some iteration over the data if the header doesn't come first - unless you are willing for the downstream consumer of the data to sort out the 'shape' of the object.

For this I'm assuming all the objects for one remote invocation have the same structure and the structure is flat.

When header comes through, save the header names in a separate variable to the data. E.g. in an array - something like this:

```
$header = @()
$data = @()

# assuming variable $remoteObject which is a psobject

If ($remoteObjIsHeader) {
  $remoteObject | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | % {
    $header += $_.Name
  }
}
else {

  $data += $remoteObject
}
```

Once you have all the header you can start pushing out your new psobjects with a function like this.

```
Function Write-DataBuffer($Headers, $Data) {

  foreach($item in $Data) {
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject

    for ($i =0; $i -lt $Headers.length; $i++) {
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Headers[$i] -Value $item[$i]
    }
    Write-Output $obj
  }

}
```

You could get fancier and buffer the contents in `$data` until the header arrives and then you will only have to loop through the number of rows received before the header arrives. But you said this is async so I'm not sure about the threading implications.

```
If ($remoteObjIsHeader) {
  $remoteObject | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | % {
    $header += $_.Name
  }
  if ($data.length -gt 0) {
      # header arrived after data - flush the buffer
      Write-DataBuffer -Data $data
  }
}
else {
  if ($headers.length -gt 0) {
    # have the headers just output the data
    Write-DataBuffer -Data @($remoteObject)
  } 
  else {
    # don't have headers - buffer the data
    $data += $remoteObject
  }
}
```